# Mocking Classes for QFTest

Tags: easymock

At my company we are trying to make tests for a GUI build on JAVA swing using an automation tool called QFTEST.

In order to get better code coverage we came to the conclusion that a mocking specific classes is necessary. My boss has directed me to learn a EasyMock. However, from reading the documentation I came to believe that EasyMock must work with JUNIT and cannot be used as a standalone... Is this correct?

The bottom line:
Is it possible to integrate EasyMock with QFTEST?
If not, do you have another idea for a solution?

Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

Though I've not used easymock, we have used mockito (very similar) and we have used qftest separately. There should be no reason why you need junit to use either mockito or easymock as these two will work with testng for example. You will just need to decide how you will make your calls to easy mock/mockito as I think you have a choice of jython/groovy to write extended scripts.

Regards,
Mike